# Test component metadata

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

We just would like to test ChangeDetection value on few components but we don't find a way to access easly to component metadata.
For pipe we have found:

```
it('should be marked as pure', () => {
        expect(new PipeResolver().resolve(TranslatePipe).pure).toEqual(true);
    });
```

Main problem here is to find a easy way to do it for component and check if it is `OnPush` or not. Any idea here?
So thanks.

Comment: `import { PipeResolver } from '@angular/compiler';` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are looking for:

```
new DirectiveResolver().resolve(TestComponent) as Component).changeDetection
```

Full code:

```
import { Component, Pipe, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { PipeResolver, DirectiveResolver } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TestComponent {
  title = 'Test Tour of Heroes';
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate',
  pure: true
})
export class TranslatePipe {
  transform() {

  }
}


describe('BannerComponent', () => {
  it('should be marked as pure', () => {
    expect(new PipeResolver().resolve(TranslatePipe).pure).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('should be marked as onPush', () => {
    expect((new DirectiveResolver().resolve(TestComponent) as Component).changeDetection).toEqual(ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush);
  });
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/OfWMxTSJEuqLKlMhdcz0?p=preview)**

Comment: that's interesting, do you think metadata should be tested?

Comment: DirectiveResolver and PipeResolver are part of compiler API, not sure if it's public

Comment: @Maximus I am pretty certain it depends on tastes

Comment: So thanks i didn't imagine that DirectiveResolver could be used also for components.

Comment: `Directive` is a parent class of `Component`

Comment: @Maximus `not sure if it's public ` I tested it in my IDE. They are public

Comment: What do you think to use ComponentFactoryResolver? did you give it a try?

Comment: `ComponentFactoryResolver` is used for getting `ComponentFactory`. You can get component `selector` and `type`. But in order to get metadata you need to use something else, for example `Reflect.getMetadata` but i offered you easist way

Comment: Maybe you have already read this https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7

Comment: @yurzui yer for sure...anyway i really didn't think about use DirectiveResolver on our components test. So thanks!